# New Unit with Blocked Condensate Lines

Tags: hvac

A little over 30 days ago a new HVAC unit was installed at my home. Saturday night I had a buckled ceiling and a BIG problem.  The installer told me both primary and secondary lines were clogged—-the secondary had a wasp nest I am told-therefore they are not responsible-  this sounds wrong to me.  Please help.  I need to come back with a knowledgeable argument.
Thank you

Comment: what was the primary blocked with? where is the hvac installed?

Comment: They say gunk -  I live in N Cal- pretty average weather. Not humid.

Comment: The unit was installed July 13; 2019

Comment: gunk is fairly broad, any more specifics? does the hvac have a filter correctly installed?

Comment: I agree and have requested their “report”.  When the unit was installed they installed the new filters I purchased.

Comment: The unit is installed at the side of my house, with something up in the attic-  with a pan that was full  and rolled over causing the damage to my ceiling   : (

Comment: The pan under your attic mounted air handler should have a sensor installed that shuts off the unit when water collects in the pan. A clog in the primary so soon is strange unless it was some debris left by manufacturer or installer

Comment: They did not install a shut off.  I have since asked for one.  But, when I asked if they were helping with the damages things turned very tense and the company owner got very adversarial.  That is why I am seeking information, want  to make sure I have a leg to stand on before I move forward.

Comment: If they were hired to supply and install the equipment they should have included the sensors in an attic install. If you purchased the equipment and then hired them to install what you provided the responsibility may rest on you to provide all the necessary equipment to prevent an attic flood. Was a work permit pulled? Was an inspection done?

Comment: They supplied everything. ... a permit was pulled... no inspection yet.

Comment: Heads up, it's going to fail inspection. A condensate overflow shutoff is required in nearly every jurisdiction.

Comment: Where can I find out if one is required where I live?

Comment: @Sharen, you can call your city's office that handles building inspections or call another A/C company and don't tell them anything about what's going on - just ask if a overflow shutoff is required by code in your area.

Comment: Thank you.   There are options to meet code, a shut off, a secondary and/or a drain pan- therefore the AC company is ok there.  The local building department inspector thought it quite odd that both lines would be clogged at the same time, for the first time and believes it’s quite e possible the problem occurred because something was or was not done at the time of installation 